# Consider the following system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following model. Find the general solution

$\frac{dx}{dt}=-2y$,
$\frac{dy}{dt}=8x$

So far this is what I have:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-2y$$
$$x'=-2y$$
$$y=-\frac{x'}{2}$$
$$y=-\frac{x''}{2}$$
and then
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=8x$$
$$y'=8x$$
$$-\frac{x''}{2}=8x$$
$$-x''=16x$$
$$x''+16x=0$$ 
Is this correct so far? What step should I take next?

Comment: If $r^2+16=0$ then $r= \pm 4i$ hence you get $\sin(4t), \cos (4t)$ as fundamental solutions for $x$. ( I have not checked your steps)

Comment: Why do you self-duplicate your questions?

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall why did you change the values of the constants in the question by removing the decimal points?

Comment: Well, this question is thoroughly hosed now due to an editing error which occurred _because OP did not use MathJax in the first place._ And then instead of correcting the error and explaining what happened (so that the answers would still make sense), OP copied the original to a new question. What a mess!

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Good question. Several reasons. Firstly, it was very unclear that these were decimal points. They seemed to be some crude form of manual formatting. I did not dismiss that possibility initially, but when a .8 was doubled it became a .16 in the working (???) so I assumed it couldn't have been a decimal point.

This was apparently an error. And I apologise. The edit was in good faith, but I have learnt my lesson: assume nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Although not the usual way I've seen this done (usually I have seen the eigenvalue/eigenvector method done), your approach works.

Now you need to know that the general solution to $x''+16x=0$ is $c_1 \cos(4x) + c_2 \sin(4x)$. One way to see this is to get the characteristic polynomial $\lambda^2+16$ which has roots $\pm 4i$. So from this you get a general solution of $c_1 e^{4ix} + c_2 e^{-4ix}$ for complex constants $c_1,c_2$. That can then be rearranged into the previous form.

Comment: how do you know the general solution c1e4ix+c2e−4ix can be rewritten as c1cos(4x)+c2sin(4x) is that from Euler's formula?

Comment: @Lil That's right; it is not too hard to see from Euler's formula that $\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$ and $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$.

Comment: alright, how do I go about finding the value of c1 and c2?

Comment: @Lil For the general solution you don't have to; the general solution has two arbitrary constants in it. You get the constants from initial conditions.

Comment: alright. The equations represent a fictions situation of two people and I'm suppose to analyze which person would suffer more. Do I need the constants for that?

Comment: @Lil I don't think I have enough specifics to answer your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22822/discussion-between-lil-and-ian).

Answer (score 0):

The next step is to slove the last equation you have:
$$
x'' + 16 x = 0$$
with the ansatz that 
$$x(t) = e^{kt}$$
You quickly find that 
$$x'' = k^2 e^{kt} \\
k^2 + 16 = 0\\
k = \pm 4i
$$
and since the equation in linear the general solution is the arbitrary llinear combination
$$x(t) = c_1 e^{4it} + c_2 e^{-4it}$$ which can be rearranged to 
$$x(t) = A \sin(4t) + B \cos (4t)$$
Finally, you read off $y(4)$ as $$y(t)=-\frac12 \frac{dx}{dt} = -\frac{A}{2} \cos (4t) + \frac{B}{2} \sin (4t)$$

Comment: how do I go about finding the coefficients, A and B?

Comment: You asked for the general solution of the system of equations.   Any values you choose for $A$ and $B$ work and solve the system.  For a problem with boundary values or initial conditions, $A$ and $B$ may be determined by those constraints.  For example, if I told you that $y(0) = 1, y'(0) = 2$ then that would force $A=2$ and $B=1$.

Answer (score -1):

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-2y$$
$$\frac{dt}{dx}=-\frac{1}{2y}$$
By chain rule:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\cdot\frac{dt}{dx}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=8x\cdot-\frac{1}{2y}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{4x}{y}$$
$$y\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=-4x$$
$$\int y\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}dx=\int-4xdx$$
$$\int ydy=-4\int xdx$$
$$\frac{y^2}{2}+c_1=-4\cdot\frac{x^2}{2}$$
$$y^2+c_2=-4x^2$$
$$y^2+4x^2+c_2=0$$
Where $2c_1=c_2$, and $c_1$ is a constant of integration.